# Why WebdriverIO makes POST 'element' request for webelement that is never used?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I was playing around with webdriverIO, it looks pretty nice! I already love a lot of features of this framework.

I was investigating how WebdriverIO works with non-existing elements and lazy element loading with this test:

```
it('no element, and not used', () => {
    browser.pause(5000)
    let non_exist = browser.$('.nonexist')
});
```

runner output:

````
```
[17:23:25]  COMMAND    POST     "/wd/hub/session/6b79fd07-5f5d-42ce-b1e5-f99734aae128/element"
[17:23:25]  DATA                {"using":"css selector","value":".nonexist"}
```
````

webdriver server log:

````
```
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.nonexist}
17:23:25.840 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 6b79fd07-5f5d-42ce-b1e5-f99734aae128])
```
````

So as i see WebdriverIO still sends POST request to selenium server, and tries to find element on declaration.

Lets now see second test. Here i am declaring element, that is not exist on the page, but trying to use it later:

```
it('no element, used later in the code', () => {
    browser.pause(5000)
    let myElem = browser.$('.nonexist')
    console.log('AND NOW FAIL!')
    console.log(myElem.getText())
});
```

Test runner output:

````
```
[17:30:35]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/05e4115c-ed66-4e47-8a01-c37208d379ab/element"
[17:30:35]  DATA                {"using":"css selector","value":".nonexist"}
AND NOW FAIL!
[17:30:36]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/05e4115c-ed66-4e47-8a01-c37208d379ab/elements"
[17:30:36]  DATA                {"using":"css selector","value":".nonexist"}
[17:30:36]  RESULT              []
```
````

Selenium Server logs:

````
```
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.nonexist}
17:30:36.133 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: .nonexist])
17:30:36.155 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: .nonexist]
```
````

Webdriver IO sends 2 requests - first on declaration, and then 'elements' request on attempt to apply some action on this element.

So the question is, why do WebdriverIO trying to find element twice in my examples? Exception is not thrown, everything is good, but i just wondering is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Even though the [Webdriver Spec](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#find-element) states that if an element was not found the driver should throw an exception WebdriverIO doesn't. The reason behind this is that in WebdriverIO you can call actions on elements that don't exist. This is for syntax reasons. It allows to define elements in variables and then use it later on like:

```
var myElem = $('#notExisting')
myElem.waitForExist() // waits for element to exist
console.log(myElem.getText()) // returns text if elem shows up
```

However WebdriverIO is smart enough to fail if you want to call an action on the element if it doesn't exist like you mentioned above:

```
var myElem = $('#notExisting')
console.log(myElem.getText()) // THROWS EXCEPTION
```

One disadvantage of this design is that queries on non existing elements take a little bit more time than on elements that exist but in long term is neglectable. Obviously the advantage is better and easier to read test code which saves way more time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that lazy-elements should not throw exceptions on declarations, this is really good approach (for my opinion). But i want to now why do we even need to send POST request on declaration (see first test in question).

Comment: Because we don't know if an element showed up in the mean time. It basically re fetches it

Comment: Also in case the element exist in the first place we reuse the reference we got from the driver so that we don't have to fetch the element again